# Exec command in Ant only executes first command

Tags: linux, bash, ant, exec, ant-contrib

I want to list the permission of every script in directory `dir/bin`. But the below command only runs `"ls"` in the directory where the script is with below code rather than every script in `dir/bin`. Since `script.xml` is there in maindir, it just does a `ls` inside maindir.

**There are 2 problems:**

1. Performing `ls -l` & not just the 1st command in the line
2. Performing `ls -l` in right directory instead of directory where the script is.

**The directory structure:**

```
   - maindir
     - dir
        -bin
          -test.sh
          -con.py
     - script.xml
```

**Below code is called "script.xml":**

```
<foreach param="dirSc" in="dir/bin">
    <exec executable="/bin/sh"
        resultproperty="returncode"     
        output="dir/output.txt">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg line="ls -l ${dirSc}" />
   </exec>
<foreach>
```

Comment: foreach is not a standard ANT task. Part of the 3rd party "ant-contrib" extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the [apply task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) to run commands against a series of files.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
└── dir
    └── bin
        ├── con.py
        └── test.sh
```

Produces the following output

```
scan:
    [apply] -rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 1 Jun 23 23:30 ../dir/bin/con.py
    [apply] -rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 1 Jun 23 23:29 ../dir/bin/test.sh
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="scan">

  <target name="scan">
    <apply executable="ls">
      <arg value="-l"/>
      <fileset dir="dir"/>
    </apply>
  </target>

</project>
```